# .NET 6 referencing .Net 4.8 with old WCF Dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf

I have a .Net 6.0 application that references an old .Net 4.8 project which uses WCF.

The .Net 4.8 project needs a number of DLLS not in .NET 6.0 like System.Web.Services.

When I run the .Net 6.0 application and call the .NET 4.8 project, I get an error that System.Web.Services can't be found.

How can I tell the .Net 4.8 project where System.Web.Services is?

Comment: That's an invalid setup. .NET 6 projects can only consume .NET Core or .NET Standard class libraries without problems. If you still have any .NET Framework class libraries, migrate them (and get rid of WCF) or you just see more and more issues like this. (Yes, Microsoft allows .NET 6 projects to consume .NET Framework projects, but that only introduces unnecessary problems for beginners).

Answer (score 2):

[Using .NET Framework compatibility mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#net-framework-compatibility-mode) does not guarantee what will happen.
If you want your library to have solid cross-framework compatibility between .NET Framework and .NET Core/6, you can try targeting your library in [.NET Standard](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/dotnet-standard).
For an alternative to WCF, you can look at:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation